# function inside andThen() not emitting onComplete()

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-android

Here is my stream:

```
public Completable changeUserPassword(String oldPass, String newPass){
        return firebaseAuthRepositoryType.getCurrentUser()
                .flatMapCompletable(fu -> firebaseAuthRepositoryType.reAuthenticateUser(fu,fu.getEmail(),oldPass)
                   .andThen(firebaseAuthRepositoryType.changeUserPassword(fu, newPass)))
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
}
```

Problem is the function inside `andThen()` never calls `onComplete()`? and the stream is "stuck" there. The return type of `changeUserPassword()` is `Completable`.

I tried to change out the function inside `andThen()` to `Completable.complete()` for debugging purposes but I saw the same behaviour. It still never "completes" and gets stuck in `andThen()`

Am I missing something here? Any suggestions?

The flow of the stream is supposed to be:

- **getcurrentuser()**: *returns* user ->
- **reauthuser(user**): *returns* Completable.onComplete() ->
- **user.changepass()**: *returns* Completable.complete()->
- *return* Completable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase is notorious with its never ending sequences so most likely `firebaseAuthRepositoryType.getCurrentUser()` never completes if it is an `Observable` or `Flowable`. Change it to `Single` or use `take(1)` to get one user.

Comment: Thanks for the help! That makes sense, I chose take(1) since it was better suited for my design.